# How to override "!important" into my site?

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, overriding

I have one strange issue with my website. I work on this [site](https://www.calarttech.edu)

and want to change main menu hover links from white to orange. This is the CSS from that part:

```
.darkheader .navigation > ul > li.menu-item:hover > a.menu-link,
.darkheader .navigation > ul > li.menu-item.menu-item-has-children:hover > a.menu-link 
{
color: #fff !important;
```

I wanted to change that hover to white, and tried to override white with orange color. I inserted the following CSS:

```
.darkheader .navigation > ul > li.menu-item:hover > a.menu-link,
.darkheader .navigation > ul > li.menu-item.menu-item-has-children:hover > a.menu-link 
{
color: #f06623 !important;
```

But after reloading the page, hovers on links are still white. I am wondering why the white color is not being overwritten by the orange color. I know that last CSS with !important rule is last one, and overrides all before placed. I tried to find that CSS line in theme CSS files, but can't find it nowhere. Someone to help me how to change that hover to orange?

Comment: The browser's developer tools can show you where a CSS rule is defined. Use the tools.

Comment: Just as @CharlotteDunois pointed, you can inspect with the developer tools. Alternatively, can add our own custom styling in either the theme's custom style slot or add our own css files and add the rule you want. Add important too so the default is overridden...

Comment: Thanks for reply.

I checked with Firebug, but show me only siteurl#8 line 346. Check image.

http://i.imgur.com/tEPHV4t.jpg?1

So i dont know in what file is defined that rule to remove !important from there.

I inserted into CustomCSS as you say, but still changes is not visible on site. Check image: http://i.imgur.com/YwbQmR3.png?1

Comment: Firebug... since FF has its own dev tools, I don't use Firebugs anymore. Well, clicking on the siteurl thing with the line should get you to the resource. With the HTTP url you can find out, which resource on your system the css rule defines and you can update it.

Comment: I made the same override as you in chrome and it works there (targeted element with ctrl+shift+c and changed the color). Maybe it's firefox specific or the error is not in CSS? I heard stories where people did stuff offline and forgot to upload changes.

Comment: Yes i checked, but only show me that is showed i image i posted. No URL for affected file.. that confuse me. For some CSS rules i can find direct URL what is file affected, but for this, i cant fint it.I also made the changes in firebug, and changes persist on site, but when try to add that rule in CustomCSS, nothing happens. Can you tell me what to change ?

Comment: You just need to reference your custom file below the other one...

Comment: How to do that? Can you teach me?

Comment: Ricky_Ruiz is correct, however for a quick test try adding this line to your custom styles and be sure to purge cache: body .darkheader .navigation >ul >li.menu-item:hover >a.menu-link, .darkheader .navigation >ul >li.menu-item.menu-item-has-children:hover >a.menu-link { color: orange !important; }

Comment: @Adrianopolis just tested your answer into custom CSS and flush the cache, but not worked..

Comment: @Dr.MTR In the `<head>` tag of your HTML file, you will see `<link>` tags with a `.css` file extension in the `href` attribute. Make sure the `<link>` tag referencing your custom file is below the file you are trying to override a class from.

Comment: I checked, but cant find that rule nowhere in that .css files. As you can see in source, the https://www.calarttech.edu/?sccss=1&ver=4.6.1 is bellow all other css files.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `nav` with your parent element or `class` or `id`

```css
nav .darkheader .navigation > ul > li.menu-item:hover > a.menu-link,
nav .darkheader .navigation > ul > li.menu-item.menu-item-has-children:hover > a.menu-link 
{
color: #f06623 !important;
}
```

Comment: I inserted this code into custom CSS, but failed to change nothing on site..

mainmenu .darkheader .navigation > ul > li.menu-item:hover > a.menu-link,
mainmenu .darkheader .navigation > ul > li.menu-item.menu-item-has-children:hover > a.menu-link 
{
color: #f06623 !important;
}

Comment: Insert your new CSS under

`.darkheader .navigation > ul > li.menu-item:hover > a.menu-link,
.darkheader .navigation > ul > li.menu-item.menu-item-has-children:hover > a.menu-link 
{
color: #fff !important;`

Comment: or insert your fiddle, so I can directly check it

Comment: How you meen to insert Fiddle? I dont know in what .css file is located that css rule, so i can override it.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is executed procedurally. To override an `!important` css-rule, simply define another css-rule further down in the CSS-file with the `!important` flag.

```
// First we set the color to blue    
.div1 {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
// The background color is changed to green
.div1 {
    background-color: green !important;
}
// The backgorund color is NOT changed to red, due to the !important flag above.
.div1 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hi !

Im not sure that this sollution will help me, because i tryed it before , and dont changes nothing. Read before comments :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to html, add a ID, it will increase the specificity.
But with you don't have acces to html, try override the specificity by this snippet:

```
.darkheader .navigation > ul > li.menu-item:hover > a.menu-link..menu-link,
.darkheader .navigation > ul > li.menu-item.menu-item-has-children:hover > a.menu-link.menu-link 
{
color: #f06623 !important;
```

Comment: Hi !

 I inserted code you send me into CustomCSS, but nothnig changed. I also flushed cache before check, but nothing changed.

Comment: Anyone ? Please i need other possible sollutions.